# Probability of a committee with no men

Tags: probability

I have the following problem:

There's a group of $10$ people, composed by $6$ men and $4$ women. We want so choose a committee with a president, a vice president and a treasurer. What is the probability of the committee not having any men?

What I did was that if the committee has no men, then it's all women. Thus, we choose $3$ out of the $4$ women and then we divide it by all possible committees. This is: $\frac{4 \times 3 \times 2}{10 \times 9 \times 8} = 0.0333$. But the solution says that the correct answer is $0.9667$. How did it get to this number and is my approach correct? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you sure the question asked for *no men* and not that the question asked for *at least one man*?  Note that $0.9667 + 0.0333 = 1$.  That being said... please *only* use equals signs for *equality*... not for approximations.  $\frac{4\cdot 3\cdot 2}{10\cdot 9\cdot 8} = \frac{1}{30} = 0.03333333333333\cdots = 0.0\overline{3} \neq 0.0333$

Comment: Apart from rounding when you shouldn't, your answer and approach are correct for the problem as written given several natural assumptions (*such as each arrangement being equally likely, etc...*) and the answer of $0.9\overline{6}$ is the answer to the question of *at least one man* being present.

Comment: I agree with JMoravitz